# NerManager (from nlp.js) is incorrectly extracting entities like system("pre-trained") entities

Tags: node.js, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using NerManager with a threshold of 0.8. I have very specific set of training samples that I am adding into the function (NOTE: The following is a sample code and is showing about 30% of the total training samples)

It's correctly extracting the entity "AB_99876" from the input text, but the issue I am having is that it's also extracting "Today", "01/01/2019", "test@email.com" and "(123)-456-7890".

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the sample code:

```
const { NerManager } = require('node-nlp');

const manager = new NerManager({ threshold: 0.8 });

manager.addNamedEntityText(
'sample_a', 
'category_a',
['en'],
['AB_12345','AB_54321','AC_12245','AC_12355','BA_12345','BA_87653','AC_99876','DC_54321','BC_12232'],
);

manager.findEntities(
'Today 01/01/2019 is a good day. My email is test@email.com and phone is (123)-456-7890 and the the number I am looking for is AB_99876',
'en',
).then(entities => {
  // I look for the value in the utteranceText field and process the extracted entity for next steps. 
}).catch(err => {
console.log('Error getting entity extracted', err);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass additional configuration **builtinWhitelist** to NerManager.
By default all built in entities are processed.

`const manager = new NerManager({
  threshold: 0.8,
  builtinWhitelist: [],
});`